# vue-bulma-datepicker closes when selecting a year in Firefox

Tags: firefox, datepicker, vuejs2, vue-component

Is there anyone here using this package vue-bulma-datepicker? I tested the datepicker in firefox when I select a year the datepicker closes.

Did you guys encounter this? any workaround for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with creating my own vue component instead.

https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-flatpickr-component

```
npm install vue-flatpickr-component --save
```

Here is how to use it.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <flat-pickr v-model="date"></flat-pickr>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import flatPickr from 'vue-flatpickr-component';
  import 'flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css';

  export default {    
    data () {
      return {
        date: null,       
      }
    },
    components: {
      flatPickr
    }
  }
</script>
```